# Does $ord(b^2) = ord(b) = p(rime) \neq 2$ imply $(b) = (b^a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$(b)$ contains all elements of the form $b^m$ where $m \in \mathbb Z$ and so $b^2 \in (b)$ and $(b^2 ) \subseteq (b)$. I can't seem to show the converse since I can't find an integer $m$ such that $b^{2m} = b$.

If the claim is true, what can I do to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ord(b^2) = ord(b)$ implies $|(b^2)| = |(b)|$.

Since $(b^2) \subseteq (b)$, we must have $(b^2) = (b)$.

Comment: Note that this does not depend on $ord(b)$ being a prime nor on the exponent $2$.